# Iterate through array comparing dictionary values

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a NSMutableArray *dataArray containing NSDictionaries. I want to iterate through the array in order to create a new NSMutableArray *tempDataArray with objects from the first array if the searchString matches one of the dictionaries values.

Here is my code:

```
self.tempDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < kDelegate.dataArray.count; i++) {

    NSDictionary *dict = [kDelegate.dataArray objectAtIndex:i];

    for (int j = 0; j < [dict allValues].count ; j++) {

        if ([[[[dict allValues] objectAtIndex:j]stringValue] isEqualToString:searchString]) {

            [self.tempDataArray addObject:dict];
        }
    }

}
```

Now this doesn't work because the dictionary also contains a NSDate. At least that is what I am reading from the error message:

```
-[__NSTaggedDate stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x41b7809e2600000d
```

Which I dont understand, because I do declare all the values as stringValue.

That was the first part of my problem. The second half is that this only searches for an exact match but I would rather have a search determining if the dictionaries values contain a substring.

Anyway, thanks for all your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "declaring all the values as stringValue"? It's not meaningful... Also, read the exception message. It tells you that you're trying to send the `stringValue` message to an `NSDate` which it doesn't implement, of course.

Comment: I meant this line: `[[[dict allValues] objectAtIndex:j]stringValue]`
Shouldn't that take care of the date and convert it to a string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(untested):

```
self.tempDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < kDelegate.dataArray.count; i++) {

    NSDictionary *dict = [kDelegate.dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *allValues = [dict allValues];

    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < allValues.count; j++) {
        NSObject *obj = [allValues objectAtIndex:j];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            NSRange range = [(NSString *)obj rangeOfString:searchString];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                [self.tempDataArray addObject:dict];
            }
        }
    }
}
```